# Dell Precision M4800: Black screen after login with new 18.04 install

Tags: boot, system-installation, login

What happens (and I've repeated this a few times) is that I'll:

1. Install 18.04.1 (to be safe: minimal installation, no 3rd party packages).
2. Reboot, removing the USB stick in the progress.
3. Login into Ubuntu successfully (just once).
4. Restart the computer. When I login, I'll get a black screen after successfully entering my password and hitting enter. Eventually I just force reset.

I'll rarely be able to get back in later, but it's not clear what makes it work (race condition?).

Before logging in, I can get to a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-F2 (and `startx` if necessary).

NVIDIA video card:

```
david@david-Precision-M4800:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)
```

Here's a relevant portion of `/var/log/syslog` (attempted login):

```
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loader magic: 0x5624fd87d020
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module ABI versions:
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (++) using VT number 3
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_34
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 12 paused 1
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Error systemd-logind returned paused fd for drm node
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 13 paused 1
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Error systemd-logind returned paused fd for drm node
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:1
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:1028:05cc rev 6, Mem @ 0xf5400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:0ff6:1028:15cc rev 161, Mem @ 0xf4000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "glx"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: Permission denied
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: Permission denied
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Unloading modesetting
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 22052)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Unloading fbdev
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 22052)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Unloading vesa
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 22052)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: Permission denied
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: Permission denied
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: message repeated 2 times: [ (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"]
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: Fatal server error:
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) no screens found(EE)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]:  for help.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/david/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE)
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1341]: Unable to run X server
Sep  8 08:26:52 david-Precision-M4800 gdm3: GdmDisplay: display lasted 1.219869 seconds
Sep  8 08:26:58 david-Precision-M4800 kernel: [   71.964576] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
Sep  8 08:28:28 david-Precision-M4800 kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x25, date = 2018-04-02
Sep  8 08:28:28 david-Precision-M4800 systemd-modules-load[295]: Inserted module 'lp'
Sep  8 08:28:28 david-Precision-M4800 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-33-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-024) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-33.36-generic 4.15.18)
```

Comment: Does it have the AMD or Nvidia graphics? If the AMD, try disabling the `amdgpu` driver to force it to use the `radeon` (on my M4800 both were loaded after the 18.04 upgrade). To do so, add `modprobe.blacklist=amdgpu` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub`, and `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: @zwets It actually has NVIDIA graphics (Quadro K1100M)

Comment: It will be useful to add that fact to the question, as well as any other things you have tried. Note that there are multiple questions already about issues with 18.04 and nVidia, and about black screens after login.

Comment: Unlikely but let's eliminate: did you try increasing screen intensity (Fn+Up) when in the black screen? Also, check your `/var/log/syslog` and Xorg log (`~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.*.log`) for hints.

Comment: Yes, I just tried increasing the screen intensity.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the machine was just missing a device driver. When I run `ubuntu-drivers devices` it shows:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000FF6sv00001028sd000015CCbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

After installing `nvidia-driver-390` the login has been working consistently.

It wasn't clear to me that this is what needed to happen from the errors, so I'm not going to accept this answer for now.