# Kubuntu 20.04 shows only a black screen after login

Tags: kubuntu, login, startup, 20.04, plasma-5

I would like your help solving this issue. I recently installed Kubuntu 20.04 and sometimes (randomly, but specially after shutting down abruptly) the system gives no GUI after login (I'm not sure how to call it properly :) ... )

I'm gonna add some pictures to clarify what I'm saying.

[First Image - Login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ostgJ.jpg)

[Second Image - After entering password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVac7.jpg)

[Third Image - I can enter the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNHg4.jpg)

[Fourth Image - Hitting ALT + Space Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pFlw.jpg)

So, it gets to login screen as usual. After entering the password a black screen appears, with only a grey line at the bottom.
Hitting CTRL + ALT + T enters the terminal.
Hitting ALT + Space Bar shows only a grayish rectangle at the top of the screen.
Entering $shutdown -r now restarts the computer and the error is gone. I can use it perfectly.

I can reproduce this problem by pressing down the power button until the system is forced to shutdown. When it boots again, the error is there.

The computer specs are:
Lenovo S145-15API
AMD Ryzen 7
8GB RAM
256GB SSD
1920x1080
No dedicated GPU

Linux DLinux 5.4.0-28-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 17:40:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried in the terminal https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dell Precision M4800: Black screen after login with new 18.04 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062371/dell-precision-m4800-black-screen-after-login-with-new-18-04-install)

Answer (score 0):

The same happens to me. I believe it will be fixed soon but in the meanwhile, I found (by googling) the following solution. Open Konsole, and issue the next commands as a normal user:

- killall plasmashell
- plasmashell &
- disown

Then, you can freely close the Konsole window.